# How do I populate a field in an object with a value from the URI in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an endpoint:

```
[Route("cars/{carId}/wheels")]
public async Task Post([FromBody] NewWheel wheel)
```

Here is the `NewWheel` object:

```
public class NewWheel
{
    public int WheelId;
    public int CarId;
    public string BrandName;
}
```

Is there a way I can configure .net core to populate the `CarId` field in the `NewWheel` object with the `carId` in the route, without duplicating the `CarId` in the route and request body or explicitly doing so in each controller I'd like to do this?

Comment: How would it populate an object that hasn't been created yet? Or is your class object a static instance?

Comment: Are you using entity-framework and how does the actual wheel entity look like?

Comment: @RyanWilson I don't actually know how .net core creates the object it passes as the wheel object in this example. I believe my question is asking if there is a way to modify that. It is not a static instance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use model binding attributes on the model properties

```
public class NewWheel {
    public int WheelId { get; set; }
    [FromRoute]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
}
```

Also note that the model is using **public properties** and not fields.

> `FromRouteAttribute` Specifies that a **parameter or property** should be bound using route-data from the current request.

*emphasis mine*

```
/// <summary>
/// Specifies that a parameter or property should be bound using route-data from the current request.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class FromRouteAttribute : Attribute, IBindingSourceMetadata, IModelNameProvider
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public BindingSource BindingSource => BindingSource.Path;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a67d9363e22be8ef63a1a62539991e1da3a6e30e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/FromRouteAttribute.cs#L13)

Only caveat here is the route template parameters are case sensitive, so I would advise making sure the property name and template parameter match

```
[Route("cars/{CarId}/wheels")]
```

Comment: I implemented what you suggested. I added the [FromRoute] attribute to a public property on a model. I created a request with the id in the route and not in the body. The id was not populated in the object.

Comment: @Anthony and are the route names the same?

Comment: yes, and the casing is the same. Has this worked for you in the past?

Comment: @Anthony Yes and I've had no major issues binding simple models like the one in your example. I just followed what was in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Since carId is a route value, you will need to add it as a parameter.

```
[Route("cars/{carId}/wheels")]
public async Task Post([FromRoute] int carId, [FromBody] NewWheel wheel)
{
      wheel.CarID = carId; //then you can add it to the wheel object if you desire
}
```

Comment: Op "without duplicating the CarId in the route and request body or explicitly"

Comment: it depends on the OP meaning of duplicating. In this case carID is only sent in the route and left out of the request body thus removing duplication inside the request.

Comment: That seems a bit weird, your saying now client side, you will explicitly ignore a field from your object when serializing? And Server side you explicitly break model binding, just to avoid duplication?

Comment: I was just trying to answer the question. Personally I would use the route and the body to validate each other. like carId != wheel.carId then throw badrequest.

Comment: @LeeReitz that makes sense. On my team we did that but eventually felt we were creating extra work to verify the id in the route and the id in the body match for every endpoint.